# Do I need a slash in front of rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have the following url structure in rails routes:

```
match '/financial-dictionary/:letter' => 'learning_center#dictionary', :as => :lc_dictionary
```

Do i need a leading slash in front of "financial-dictionary"? What will happen if i remove it?

Comment: yes,it works both ways, i just wondering if there is any actual difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: nope, you don't need.

You might want to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html :)

Comment: thats actually where i got confused - because they are using a slash  `match "/patients/:id" => "patients#show"` in guides...

Comment: you don't need, but you can use them. They are using both in the guide.